# UpdateView and jQuery.ajax()

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

In my Django project I have a model with just a couple of fields.
But there are a lot of related objects: sets of dates, places, comments etc. 
But its DetailView shows rather a lot of things. So, I decided to update the model via ajax.
Django's UpdateView uses redirect to success_url. This seems to be the root of all the troubles.

I used this:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/#ajax-example

I checked the update form manually in the browser.

And via ajax the data is also updated on the server. But I can't catch the result via ajax.

In Chrome dev tools while debugging js I occur in fail function. 
And jqXHR.status=0, textStatus = "error", errorThrown="".

When I switch from Sources tab to Console I can read:

POST http://localhost:8000/frame/2/ 405 (Method Not Allowed)

Could you help me cope with this?

**views.py**

```
class FrameUpdate(AjaxableResponseMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Frame
    form_class = FrameUpdateForm
    template_name = "general/ajax/ajax_form.html"

    def get_success_url(self):
        success_url = reverse_lazy("frame:frame_detail_ajax",
                                   kwargs={"pk":self.object.id})
        return success_url
```

**frame.js**

```
function fail(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
    debugger;
}

function post(){
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost:8000/frame/2/update/",
        data: $("#frame_form").serialize(),
        success: show_post,
        error: fail
        });
}
```

**Added later**

**photoarchive/urls.py**

```
url(r'^frame/', include('frame.urls', namespace='frame')),
```

**frame/urls.py**

```
url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/$', FrameDetailView.as_view(), name="frame_detail"),
url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/ajax/$', FrameDetailAjax.as_view(), name="frame_detail_ajax"),
url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/update/$', FrameUpdate.as_view(), name="frame_update"),
```

**frame.js**

```
function show_post(data){
    debugger;
    var frame_form = $("#frame_form");
    frame_form.replaceWith(data);
    show_controls();
}
```

**general.js**

```
function show_controls(){
    var controls = $(".control");
    controls.addClass( "show" );
    controls.removeClass( "hidden" );
}
```

**Added later**

I have decided to start from scratch and make a simulator. The result astonished me.

If I load DetailView, then press AjaxEdit link, then not working.

But if I click Edit link, edit once by without ajax, then AjaxEdit starts working.

By the way, if I remove redefinition of form_valid from the view, nothing works at all (that is editing without ajax don't help).

Could you comment on this?

This is a link to the simulator https://Kifsif@bitbucket.org/Kifsif/ajax_update.git

**views.py**

```
class GeneralUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = General
    fields = ['char']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save()
        return render(self.request, 'general/general_detail.html', {"object": self.object})
```

**models.py**

```
class General(models.Model):
    char = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("detail", kwargs={"pk": self.id})
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^create$', GeneralCreate.as_view(), name="create"),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/detail$', GeneralDetailView.as_view(), name="detail"),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/edit$', GeneralUpdate.as_view(), name="edit"),
]
```

**general_form.html**

```
<form id="form" action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Save" />
</form>
```

**general_detail.html**

```
<p id="char">{{ object.char }}</p>

<a href="{% url "edit" object.id %}">Edit</a>
<a id="ajax_edit" href="javascript:void(0)">AjaxEdit</a>


<script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"   integrity="sha256-cCueBR6CsyA4/9szpPfrX3s49M9vUU5BgtiJj06wt/s="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
    var ajax_edit = $("#ajax_edit");
    var char = $("#char");

    function show_get(data){
        $(data).insertAfter(char);
        var submit_link = $("#submit");
        submit_link.click(post);
    }

    function show_post(data){
        debugger;
    }

    function failure(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        debugger;
    }

    function post(){
        $.ajax({
                method: "post",
                data: $("form").serialize(),
                url: 'http://localhost:8000/2/edit',
                success: show_post,
                error: failure,
                }
        )
    }

    function get(){
        $.ajax({
                method: "get",
                url: 'http://localhost:8000/2/edit',
                success: show_get,
                }
        )
    }

    ajax_edit.click(get);

    });
</script>
```

Comment: It looks like the URL of the call with the error is not the one you do on the code you posted (which is actually successful). How does show_post look like? Does it make any ajax call?

Comment: Added to the end initial post. About urls as well. I can't catch the idea of another url. The model updates. This means that I manage to occur in the post method of UpdateView. I thought that the reason was in the redirect to success_url. But now there is no redirect - I return just rendered response with code 200.